# Как найти и сохранить индекс определенного объекта из элемента списка

Tags: c#, unity3d

Суть заключается в том что: Когда коллайдер объекта "A" пересекает коллайдер  объекта "Б" индекс элемента объекта "Б" - из списка, записывается в переменную для дальнейшей манипуляцией.

У каждого объекта, который находится в списке есть свой индекс. Я перепробовал indexof, findindex, у меня выходит -1 или просто пересчитывается весь список и показывает размер списка.

Мне нужно чтобы в переменную записывался индекс N объекта (В зависимости пересечения границы коллайдера).

```
 void OnTriggerEnter(Collider box)
{
    if(box.gameObject == PropSpawn.Api.newItem)
    {
        closeLocation = true;
       numberIndex =  SpawnLocations.Api.propIndex.IndexOf(SpawnLocations.Api.propIndex.Count,0, 8);

        
    }
}
```

Comment: Чего... А можно нормально объяснить?

Comment: Простыми словами: У меня есть 9 точек локации, каждая из точек локаций записана в массив<List>, у каждой из точек локации есть коллайдер - мне нужно, чтобы, когда коллайдер объекта пересекает коллайдер точки локации, индекс элемента точки локации, которая записана в массив сохранялся в отдельной переменной.(В зависимости от того с какой точкой локации пересекся объект её индекс записывается в переменную )

Comment: @Gilly так понятно ?

Comment: Код не положено?

Comment: @aepot Исправил

Comment: @Gilly Исправил